# Set a variable value in stored procedure and use in following query

Tags: stored-procedures, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

How can I set a variable in stored procedure and use it in following query to be executed.

```
create or replace procedure sp1()
returns table (dealer_id varchar, dealershipgroup_name varchar)
language sql
as
$$
declare
  create_query varchar;
  res resultset;
  MISSING_DEALER NUMBER(38,0) default 0;
begin
  MISSING_DEALER := 100;
  select_query := 'WITH CTE AS(
                                SELECT dealer_id, 
                                CASE WHEN dealer_id=:MISSING_DEALER then \'Abc\'
                                WHEN dealershipgroup IS NULL then \'\' 
                                ELSE dealershipgroup end as dealershipgroup FROM TBL )
                     
                    select * from CTE';
                     
  res:= (execute immediate : select_query);  
  return table(res);
  
end;
$$; 

call sp1();
```

Could someone please suggest how can I use MISSING_DEALER in the query. I am currently getting the following error

> Uncaught exception of type 'STATEMENT_ERROR' on line 28 at position 9 : SQL compilation error: error line 8 at position 26 Bind variable :MISSING_DEALER not set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to concatenate the string parts of your SQL statement with the variable. This is covered in the documentation if you look at the end of the section [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowflake-scripting/variables.html#using-a-variable-in-a-sql-statement-binding)